# Load HTML-file that is using Javascript in a WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to open a **.html** page that uses **javascript** in a `WebView`.
To be explicit, I'm trying to open the demo-eBook by 1000°-ePaper.

I copied the demo-folder into my asset-folder, so there is a file called "mobile.html". This HTML-file uses some javascript and .css. It seems that it is trying to open a "mobile.html#/page/0" first.

When I load the WebView, it says: **"Please activate Javascript**".

My Code:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Prospect/test/mobile.html");
```

So it should work, right? The confusing thing is that I **can load** the mobile.html, when I put all the stuff online an use the **defaultBrowser.**

Comment: Just wondering is the "Please Activate JavaScript" message from the WebView class or is it from the HTML/JavaScript? I haven't seen it before and I have used embedded HTML and JavaScript a few times. Generally it just works with WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); so I'd imagine it's just something small going wrong somewhere. Even of your not using them I think it helps to throw in clients too e.g WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Comment: It's a message from the HTML/JavaScript. Ok, nice to hear that it should be something small.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to associate a webviewClient and WebChromeClient to your web view.

Comment: Ok, I did it like in this tutorial, but it didn't help: http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1331
I think, that the WebChromeClient just helps to show the Progress and the Webviewclient overrides the default Browser? Or have I done it in the wrong way?

Comment: You are absolutely correct about WebViewClient where as WebChromeClient is responsible for handling Javascript messages and processes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class ViewWeb extends Activity {           
     @Override         
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
     setContentView(R.layout.webview);           
     WebView mWebView;            
     mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);        
     mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
     mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);    
     mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false); 
     mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html");     
     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()); 

 private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient  {   
     @Override     
     //show the web page in webview but not in web browser   
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {      
         view.loadUrl (url);      
         return true;
     } 
 }
 mWebView.loadData("", "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: I tried that and copied the text of the HTML-file here: mWebView.loadData("HERE I copied the text of the mobile.html", "text/html", "utf-8");
Was that your thought? Unfortunately it's just showing the clear html text and ignores css/javascript code that are linked and in separate files, so I don't have Inline Code

Comment: Is the "myfile.html" in your case just a helpfile to open the webClient?

Comment: Have you tried putting in some of the stuff (JS, CSS) Inline just to see if it works? Maybe there is a linking issue?

Comment: Didn't try this till now, because the .js-code is too much. To be explicit, it's a ePaper-HTML-document that I buyed. It seems that the DOM isn't built fast enough, cause 1 out of 15 times the content is shown very well. Is it possible to spend the DOM enough time to be built? LogCat says: `couldn't execute method getWidth()` of undefined'. In the .js-file, there is: `this.body.getWidth()` .